# Filling a dataframe with a 0 and 1 vector

Tags: r, loops, vector, dataframe, fill

I have a datarame with two columns (A and B). Column A is categorical B is numeric (ranging from 0.0 to 1.0).  I want to create a column C for which the values are 1 when the value in Column B is greater than or equal to 0.5 and 0 when the value in column B is less than 0.5. Any suggestions on how to do this? The final df should look like this:

```
A = c('spA', 'spB', 'spC', 'spD') 
B = c(0.25, 0.15, 0.50, 0.75) 
C = c(0,0,1,1) 
df = data.frame(A, B, C)
```

Comment: Take a look at `?ifelse`

Comment: Try to avoid `ifelse`. Just do `transform(df, C = as.numeric(B >= 0.5))`

Comment: Or even faster `df$C <- as.numeric(df$B >= 0.5)`

Comment: @Floo0, how is it faster?

Comment: @DavidArenburg why is `ifelse` so slow relative to `transform`? And is your advice to avoid it simply because of the speed difference?

Comment: @jbaums I think it is slow because it needs to evaluate the whole vector. TBH, I don't know what *exactly* makes its so slow, but I know for sure it *is very* slow. Thus, I'm alway trying avoiding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
A = c('spA', 'spB', 'spC', 'spD')  
B = c(0.25, 0.15, 0.50, 0.75)  
df = data.frame(A, B)

df$C <- as.numeric(df$B >= 0.5)
```

@David Arenburg: Speed comparison of all 3 solutions pointed our above
To be honest i dont know why it is that much faster.

```
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  df$C <- ifelse(df$B>=0.5, 1, 0),
  transform(df, C = as.numeric(B >= 0.5)),
  df$C <- as.numeric(df$B>=0.5)
  )
```

Result:

```
Unit: microseconds
                                    expr     min       lq   median       uq    max neval
       df$C <- ifelse(df$B >= 0.5, 1, 0)  33.585  35.7580  38.1285  41.6845 140.66   100
 transform(df, C = as.numeric(B >= 0.5)) 143.821 149.7470 155.0815 164.5640 284.48   100
         df$C <- as.numeric(df$B >= 0.5)  20.546  22.9165  24.2995  27.2630  53.34   100
```

**EDIT: Lager Dataset**

```
df <- data.frame(B=runif(100000))

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  df$C <- ifelse(df$B>=0.5, 1, 0),
  transform(df, C = as.numeric(B >= 0.5)),
  df$C <- as.numeric(df$B>=0.5)
  )

Unit: microseconds
                                    expr       min        lq     median         uq       max neval
       df$C <- ifelse(df$B >= 0.5, 1, 0) 31620.826 33623.452 34529.8380 55652.9290 62707.064   100
 transform(df, C = as.numeric(B >= 0.5))   811.561   979.286  1032.6255  1248.5550  2333.137   100
         df$C <- as.numeric(df$B >= 0.5)   606.498   764.542   808.0045   979.0875 23805.112   100
```

Comment: did you just benchmark on 4 rows data set?

Comment: I did both. Just added the result for a Dataset with 100000 rows.
Result is the same. With small and big data-sets `$` is faster than  transform. It is remarkable that the quantiles dont overlap. So it is significantly faster...

Comment: Actually the variance of `$` is huge and your max value is higher by a factor of 10 so it isn't actually faster. You just happen to get better median

Comment: Not to mention that "your" solution isn't different from mine. The reason I didn't use `$` is in order to try avoiding copying the whole data set twice

Comment: Maybe i am wrong but my interpretation is more based on the quantiles not on the extreme values. As the **uq** of `$` is lower than the **lq** of `transform` my interpretation would be that in most cases `$` is faster. There might be 25% where `$` sucks and also 25% where `transform` is much faster. But i personally would go for the "majority"-Vote...

Comment: You are possibly right, but I'm getting very different results for my benchmark. It seems they are almost identical, but my guess is that it is only because R versions starting from 3.0.0 and on, are creating shallow copies of the rest of the columns in `df` and thus the performance of `$` significantly improved. My guess is that for R version before R 3.0.0, `transform` will be much more efficient